# Lining up nonconsecutive multi-line equations

Tags: equations, align

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\raggedright

From the model, 
\begin{align}
&E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) = E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \nonumber \\
&( \text{Since the first normal equation gives} \ \ Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i \ \ \text{and} \ \ \bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}) \nonumber \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} ) \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the lines

```
&E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) = E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \nonumber \\
```

and

```
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} ) \nonumber
```

are separated by the line

```
&( \text{Since the first normal equation gives} \ \ Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i \ \ \text{and} \ \ \bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}) \nonumber \\
```

Despite this, I want the line

```
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} ) \nonumber
```

to line up **at the = sign** with the first line

```
&E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) = E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \nonumber \\
```

This is why I put the `\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \`

Is it possible to somehow do this using `&`, whilst maintaining the line in the middle as it is? Or, perhaps, some other way to automatically have them align?

EDIT: The reason I had to use `&` to put the middle line as its own line is because, if I put it on the same line as the first equation, then it would go off the page margin.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply put `since the first normal equation gives $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$
and $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$.` *after* the display? There's little added value (if any) from putting the comment in the middle.

Comment: @egreg You mean after the entire multi-line equation? It’s mostly for pedagogical reasons. It clearly associates the comment with the line of the equation with which it is referring to.

Comment: And it hinders legibility and understandability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\raggedright

From the model, 
\begin{align}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) &= E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \nonumber \\
\rlap{(Since the first normal equation gives $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$)} \phantom{E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } )} \nonumber \\
& = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} ) \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @Mico Oh, my apologies. You’re right, I should have waited. I just had an answer in mind and Stefan happened to exemplify it precisely. Again, my apologies. I will avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I would put the explanatory text in a `\parbox` immediately below the material to the right of the first `=` symbol. That way, it's immediately clear that the explanatory text pertains to the material on the preceding line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % <-- new (expectation operator)
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

From the model,
\begin{align*}
\E( Y_i - \bar{Y} ) 
&= \E[(\beta_0+\beta_1 X_i) - (\beta_0-\beta_1\bar{X})]  \\
&\qquad\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{(since the first normal equation gives 
$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1\bar{X}$)}\\
&= \beta_1(X_i-\bar{X}) \,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, that looks even better than what I was trying to do! I think I will try this. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would simply set the comment *after* the display (using “because” instead of “since”). It's more legible and in style with standard mathematical practice; to the contrary, the comment in the middle will raise doubts what it refers to.

Anyway, this is how you can do it; if the comment doesn't fit on one line it will wrap, as shown in the third example.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip} % \parskip=\baselineskip is HUGE

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\devioustrick}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \kern-\ifcase\expandafter1\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mathindent\relax}{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

From the model, 
\begin{align*}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) 
&= E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \\
&= \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} )
\end{align*}
because the first normal equation gives 
$Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and 
$\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$.

From the model, 
\begin{align*}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) 
={}& E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \\
&\devioustrick{
  (since the first normal equation gives
  $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and
  $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$)
}\\
={}& \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} )
\end{align*}

From the model, 
\begin{align*}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) 
={}& E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ] \\
&\devioustrick{
  (since the first normal equation gives
  $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and
  $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$
  and since the definitive answer on life, the universe
  and everything is~$42$)
}\\
={}& \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} )
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use `\intertext` to place text between aligned equations. There is rarely any need to manually align material using 'hard' spaces. The [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides environments that meet all of the most common requirements.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
From the model,
\begin{align*}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) &= E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ]  \\
\intertext{Since the first normal equation gives $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$}
& = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} )
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this is that it removes the indentation of the middle line, which I'd prefer to keep.

Comment: @ThePointer You're removing all indentations; why should that line be indented?

Comment: @egreg I want it to be viewed as comment specifically with regards to that part of the equation, rather than something more major, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to just use `\tag`. This seems to be appropriate semantically, seeing as the text pertains to the previous equation-line.

```
From the model,
\begin{align*}
E( Y_i - \bar{ Y } ) &= E[ ( \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i ) - ( \beta_0 - \beta_1 \bar{ X } ) ]
\tag{since the first normal equation gives $Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ and $\bar{Y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}$}\\
& = \beta_1( X_i - \bar{X} )
\end{align*}
```